# Using recursive method for exponents in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have to make a recursive method which takes a double x, and int n, and return x^n. Initially I was going to just going to have something like this

```
public static double power(double x, int n){
    if(n < 1){
        return 1;
    }else{
        double total = x;
        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
            total = x*x;
            power(total,x);
    }
  }
```

But in the problem it says "a recursive definition of this operation is x^n = x · x^n−1." I'm pretty new to Java and this way seems like it wouldn't be recursive as I would simply do x*x^n-1. I'm pretty new to Java so maybe I'm just confused but I'm just looking for some clarification on how that would be relate to a recursive method.

Comment: So how do you calculate x^(n-1)?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be x*x, 1 less times than n. Which I think is what I did in the for loop.

Comment: @user3769402 watch my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way that i can find:

```
public static double power(double x, int n){
    if(n < 1){
        return 1;
    }else{
       return x * power(x, n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I always forget I can call the function within the return statement. I'm use to python so I'm still trying to figure out what I can and can't do.

Comment: @user3769402 :) good luck. This is the function on python: http://ideone.com/Ojkaai

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
public static double power(double x, double n){
            if(n <= 1)
                return x;
            return x*power(x,n-1);
}
```

By using a **for loop** you are not solving the problem recursively.
Here is an example how you would use a **for loop** and a **recursive method** to do the same thing:

```
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) //for loop
{
            System.out.print(i);
}
```

```
public void print(int i) // recursive, call this method like so: print(0);
{
    if(i<10)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        print(++i);
    }
}
```

both techniques will print out the same result:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9

Comment: Wouldn't it be considered recursive because I called the method within the method, even if its in a for loop?

Comment: Yes that is true, but you are trying to solve the problem with a recursive technique by using a for loop that calls the method.

Comment: If any of the answers are correct please vote as correct answer